# SQL Server 2008 log file growing and wont shrink. Hard Drive Space running out

Tags: sql-server-2008, transaction-log, mirroring

I have a SQL Server 2008 database which has a log file (`.ldf`) with a size of 360GB and growing every day.

The `.mdf` file is only 25GB. The hard drive is 950 GB and has 150GB free space. I want to shrink this log file so that it doesn't overrun the hard drive on the server.

I used `dbcc shrinkfile('my database log file name', 0)` but unfortunately, it doesn't shrink the file. Now I know I need to take a log backup and then run the shrink command for the file to shrink.

My problem is that I don't have enough hard drive space to take a log backup.

Is there anyway I can shrink this file?

The database is on `FULL RECOVERY MODE` with mirroring ON. Please advise. Any tips to avoid this problem in the future would also be appreciated.

Comment: Do you do backups? Full recovery model, mirroring - if there are no backups and/or an issue with mirroring the log HAS to fill up to do it's job.

Comment: How frequently the transaction log backup runs? and what is the output of ==> select log_reuse_wait_desc,* from sys.databases

Comment: @Cougar9000 Can you point to the link/s ?

Comment: Do `DBCC CHECKPOINT`